# Html.LabelFor is always displaying property name instead of value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC4 project, I am showing `Checkbox` and its corresponding `Label` so that when the label is clicked the corresponding checkbox will be checked. But when i use the `@Html.LabelFor` it is displaying property name instead of showing its value. Also when i click the label the corresponding checkbox is not getting checked. What's wrong here ?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AddOns.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AddOns[i].IsActive)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddOns[i].Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddOns[i].Id)
}
```

When i use `DisplayFor` it is showing value but not checkbox getting checked on clicking the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the label to relate to the checkbox for `IsActive`, but the label to read the `Name`. So the `LabelFor` should refer to the `IsActive` property, and the label string just gets passed in as a second param.

I think you want this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AddOns.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AddOns[i].IsActive)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddOns[i].IsActive, Model.AddOns[i].Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddOns[i].Id)
}
```